# Help identifying a sniper movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

The opening scene is set in the Balkans where two American (?) snipers are staking out a bombed-out building where hostages are being held.  A third guy shows up, kills the snipers, the hostage-takers, and the hostages then blows up the building.

The action then fast-forwards to a few years later in the US.  The villain (same guy as above) sets up his rifle on top of a building and shoots a politician/government official as he exits an airplane.

One of the politician's security detail joins a female investigator (not sure which agency) on the case.

The villain later makes another attempt at the politician's wife from the woods outside her home.  This time he brings a patsy along.

I saw this in a crowded bus so I may have gotten some details a bit wrong, not to mention the bus reached my stop in the middle of the movie.

If it helps, the villain was the only African-American (?) in the cast.

Edit:
The security detail guy seemed like he was a former sniper.  Not sure, he might even have been one of the guys "killed" in the opening scene.
Tried Googling and checking IMDB.  No luck, or maybe my search skills are bad.

Comment: When did you watch it? As in what year?

Comment: I saw it on a bus last week.

Comment: Could be [The Shooter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooter_%282007_film%29), where the villain pulling the strings is Danny Glover, but some of the details don't fit. Did the movie look old or fairly recent?

Comment: Nope, not that one.  Can't really tell the age of the movie, could be anything from the 90s to the present. Might have been a made-for-TV thing.

Comment: Did you recognize any celebrities in the movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I got it: [Sabotage](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117533/combined) from 1996.

> An ex-Navy commando (Mark Dacscos) is framed for a bungled mission to save hostages from terrorists in which he survived being shot 7 times by an assassin (Tony Todd). Years later, he is hired to protect a weapons distributor and his wife, only to have the same assassin kill them. This sets him on a mission with the assigned FBI agent (Carrie Anne Moss) to bring the killers and conspirators to justice. Graham Greene appears as Dacasco's former commander.

The bad guy is an African American sniper; and though the [only trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvPCdz09-dA) I found is dubbed in German, you can see that he tries to assassinate a person who stands near a plane. It appears that the first scene with the hostages also takes place in a bombed-out building.